# how to get rid of whitespace between HStack and TabView in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, tabbar

I have the following code, where my HStack acts as the "logo" with the tabview showing the different pages. Showing weird whitespace in between the two.

Tried almost every padding combination possible, scoured the internet for a solution but just couldnt figure it out

```
import SwiftUI

struct NewToolBar: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            VStack{
                HStack{
                    Image("hippo")
                        .resizable(resizingMode: .stretch)
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .frame(width: 50.0, height: 50.0)
                    Text("App Title")
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                TabView {
                    ContentView()
                        .tabItem {
                            Label("Home", systemImage: "house")
                        }
                       
                    DietPage()
                        .tabItem {
                            Label("Diet", systemImage: "fork.knife")
                        }
                    ExercisePage()
                        .tabItem {
                            Label("Exercise", systemImage: "figure.run")
                        }
                    GamesPage()
                        .tabItem {
                            Label("Games", systemImage: "gamecontroller")
                        }
                    InfoPage()
                        .tabItem{
                            Label("Information",systemImage:"info.circle")
                        }
                }
                .tint(.white) // <- change the color of each tab icon
                .frame(maxHeight:.infinity)
                .onAppear {
                    let tabBarAppearance = UITabBarAppearance()
                    tabBarAppearance.backgroundColor = .systemPink
                    UITabBar.appearance().scrollEdgeAppearance = tabBarAppearance
                }
            }

        }.padding(0)
        
    }
}
struct NewToolBar_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        NewToolBar()
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `VStack(spacing: 0)` work?